# How to get a list of rows which exist in one dataframe and do not exist in the second one in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes - one is database and another one is actual list.
Database: [list of skills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41JPx.png)

| skills |
| --- |
| skill1 |
| skill2 |
| skill3 |
| skill4 |

List: [list of pairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrAEA.png)

| worker | skills_of_worker |
| --- | --- |
| worker1 | skill1 |
| worker1 | skill2 |
| worker1 | skill3 |
| worker2 | skill2 |
| worker2 | skill3 |
| worker2 | skill4 |
| worker3 | skill1 |
| worker3 | skill3 |
| worker3 | skill4 |

How can I get a list of pairs worker-skills, which are in Database, but not in list?:[what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK7VL.png)

| worker | skills_they_dont_have |
| --- | --- |
| worker1 | skill4 |
| worker2 | skill1 |
| worker3 | skill2 |

I tried different ways of merging and dropind duplicates, but, because of actual list of workers il pretty long, the duplicates exists for skills.

Comment: I imagined there was a typo in your output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a dataframe of all workers and skills (by cross joining them) and then left joining that to the workers df to find which combinations don't exist; that being the skills that each worker doesn't have:

```py
workers = pd.DataFrame({
    'worker': ['worker1', 'worker1', 'worker1', 'worker2', 'worker2', 'worker2', 'worker3', 'worker3', 'worker3'],
    'skills_of_worker': ['skill1', 'skill2', 'skill3', 'skill2', 'skill3', 'skill4', 'skill1', 'skill3', 'skill4']
})
skills = pd.DataFrame({'skills': ['skill1', 'skill2', 'skill3', 'skill4']})

all_workers = pd.Series(workers['worker'].unique(), name='worker')
res = skills.merge(all_workers, how='cross').merge(workers, how='left', left_on=['worker', 'skills'], right_on=['worker', 'skills_of_worker'])
res = res[res['skills_of_worker'].isna()].drop('skills_of_worker', axis=1).rename(columns={'skills':'skills_they_dont_have'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  skills_they_dont_have   worker
0                skill1  worker2
1                skill2  worker3
2                skill4  worker1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) operations ([`difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)), then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
skills = {'skill1', 'skill2', 'skill3', 'skill4'}

out = (
  df.groupby('worker', as_index=False)['skills_of_worker']
   .agg(skills.difference)
   .explode('skills_of_worker')
   .rename(columns={'skills_of_worker': 'skills_they_dont_have'})
)
```

Output:

```
    worker skills_they_dont_have
0  worker1                skill4
1  worker2                skill1
2  worker3                skill2
```